# Problem with sending Email when user clicks on Upcoming Birthday List

Tags: list

I have created upcoming birthdays list with employees pictures,then if i click on the picture i need to send birthday wish through Email.This is working in some machine and not working in some other machines

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you are creating this implementation?  Are you looking for a script to run?

Comment: im running this through script @BrandonC. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Did you want to do this through Jscript clientside, or c# server side?

Comment: Jscript client side

Comment: I posted my answer, but it is untested, so it might not work as is.  Just know that to do it client side, you need to have your picture field AND your email field showing.

Comment: actually this is working in some machine....what might be the problem!!!

Comment: Oh, right, this works on some.  What is the difference between the ones that work and the ones that don't?  Are they all running the same versions of everything?  Like, same browser versions, same script versions?

Comment: yeah we have same version,,in some machine if they click on picture mail is opening. But in some case if we click on the picture it doesn't do so!!!

Comment: Is there anything different about these machines that they have in common?  Does it always work on some, and never work on others?  Maybe on some, you ran the script once, and it never terminated, so even though you made a new one that worked, those machines are still running the old, broken script?

Comment: I found one problem with my machine, for your reference im telling this. Im unable access the links from  other sites also.Here then what might be the Problem???

Comment: could you please help me in this problem!!!

Comment: Sorry, with the limited information, I have no idea how to help.  My best plan of attack for this, though, would be to find out what makes the machines that don't run the script different from those that do.  I suspect a versioning error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to approach this is to use JQuery to select appropriate field values.  Make sure you list their email address somewhere in the page, so that we can give it to the picture. Give each column field used for pictures a ID to identify them with (So like ).  We want all pictures to have the same ID, so the script can do it all at once.  Now, as a preface, I'm not using JQuery where I am, so I don't have a way to test this.  You could try writing something like:

```
function giveEmail() {
  var $emailName = $("#ID_of_picture_field").closest("tr").find("#ID_of_email_field").text();
  //We are getting setting our focus on the field with the picture, then zooming out to the entire row.
  //We then find the text value of the email address, by finding the field with the email ID
  //So now, $emailName should be "example@example.com"

  $("#ID_of_picture_field").attr("href", "mailto:" + $emailName
       +"&body" + escape("happy birthday!"));
  }
  $(document).ready(giveEmail());
```

I think this will work.  Like I said, I have no way of testing it.  But the idea is, for each picture (with the field assigned an ID), we grab the text value out of the email field, and append an href to the picture to send an email to the email we grabbed from the row.